# how to get customer selected shipping method code from quote in magento2

Tags: magento2, php, cart, quote

how to get shipping method carrier code as $rate->getCarrier() from quote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this code

```
$shippingMethod = $quote->getShippingAddress()->getShippingMethod();

$shippingMethodArr = explode('_', $shippingMethod);

$carrierCode = $shippingMethodArr[0];
```

Comment: thank you working for me

Comment: You're very welcome! I'm happy to help